# Paper clip - stored image path inside active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, activeadmin

All the files uploaded by paper clip are beeing stored inside public/system/images/pictures/ and lots of 000/000/002 folders and etc.

I Want to use image_tag inside one active admin's view to print all the images related to one gallery.
I can get the image object, and of course the image name, but how i figure out the right stored path?

Answer (score 1):

Just call `url` on the image object, like this:

```
<% @gallery.images.each do |image| %>
  <%= image_tag image.url %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Because my peper_clip in image model config: has_attached_file :picture, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }  I had to pass like: image_tag image.picture.url.